# jQuery selector object does not update on the fly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to validate a form by checking the required fields with a jQuery selector.

```
function validate() {
  if ($('input[required][value=""]').length != 0) {
    console.log("required value missing");
  }
  return false; // to prevent firing default action
}
```

There are a couple input elements like so, with the value set in PHP (not shown):

```
<input id="id" name="name" type="text" required\>
```

The problem is that this validate function will read the DOM correctly the first time (i.e will correctly recognize all required, empty inputs), but once I fill in/delete values the  function will keep returning the same set as before, not recognizing the newly empty fields 
or the newly filled fields. Once I refresh the page, however, the selector will correctly grab the right inputs.

I saw the .live() function, but that applies to events.

Does the $(selector) cache (only checks the DOM once instantiated) or is there some other arcane/simple rule for jQuery selectors I'm not paying attention to?

Comment: So, just to clarify - this validate() function is being called every time focus is lost on a field? Or, rather, my question is, when is this function being called? Can you verify that the selectors aren't catching the new state of the DOM elements, or is it just that perhaps the function isn't being called?

Comment: @jwir3 It's being called on the submit button (onclick). I do know that it's being called, because I actually have a console log of the selector object itself. Every time I hit the submit button, it prints the same list of input elements no matter what I fill in, until I refresh the page (note: with php, the values are preserved across page refreshes)

Comment: Gotcha - I was just curious because I recently had a problem where I didn't verify that the code was getting called, and searched for a while before giving myself a well-deserved face palm.  ;) Just wanted to save you from the stinging palm if I could.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `value` attribute; use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val).

```
function validate() {
    var $missing = $('input[required]').filter(function (){
        return $(this).val() === '';
    });

    if ($missing.length != 0) {
        console.log("required value missing");
    }
    return false; // to prevent firing default action
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. The issue is that value is the hmtl markup, not what is set runtime. Thanks. btw, I think you mean var missing.